# Imported .ovpn files always prompt for both certificate password + user password instead of just the user password

Tags: gnome, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

Maybe I'm doing something wrong on my end, but this is working without any issues in all my Windows clients, and would like to get some help from someone who gets what I'm doing wrong here.

The moment I do an export of a opnvpn user profile (from an OPNsense firewall) which has an internally generated certificate from the CA (without a password on the exported cert itself.)
no matter what I do, it always keeps prompting me for BOTH the cert and the user password on the Ubuntu client where I set up the profile, even tho the certificate password does not even exist, and is not configured at all.

When configuring this exact same profile in a windows client in openvpn-GUI (v2.5.0, but GUI version doesn't matter on windows clients it seems)
all I have to do is input my username and password, as expected. after that it builds the connection and works just fine.

In Ubuntu, I cannot NOT input a certificate password. The options all get auto-detected from the .opvn config file and as such it's set by default to 'certificate and password' login type. But changing the logon type to only 'password', just aborts the connection instantly when activating the VPN.

However in the previous option the cert password seems to be mandatory and wont let me continue without it.
Also I WANT to use the exported certificate with the profile for at least the host validation, but the certificate does not HAVE a password. So how can I enter the password for it when it does not exist on the actual certificate?

Am I configuring this in the wrong way, or am I not taking something else into account?
I tested with multiple different user exports and works in windows every time, only sporadically in Ubuntu.
Additional info below for this issue.

My VPN user profile export has these files:

```
username.ovpn

username.p12

username.key
```

network-manager-openvpn-gnome version:

```
groovy,now v1.8.12-2 amd64 [installed]
```

Ubuntu release version:

```
v20.10
```

kernel info:

```
Linux $HOSTNAME 5.8.0-38-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 12 12:42:13 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

BTW, I've been having this problem for a while now. Not just this gnome/ubuntu version but 18.04 with shell 3.36 too. Might be related to the open-vpn server version running on the firewalls, but I'm not convinced. I have this problem with many exported profiles across many corporate environments with different firewalls and versions and they all have this problem.
I would really like it to be fixed since I need my VPN config imports to be hassle free considering the amount of different ones I need.

Answer (score -1):

Tell NetworkManager not to use Certificate password.
It will still ask for it, and wont accept an empty password, but it will never use it.
So just type anything in the certificate password field, and you will get connected.